# How to get the selected row from a TreeView

Tags: treeview, gtk, vala

I have a treeView with two columns. I've this method which is supposed to be call when a row is selected :

```
private Aircraft get_selected_aircraft () {
}
```

It will return an Aircraft from the registration of the first column. But how to get this registration? I have a `TreeSelection` and I can use [`get_selected_rows ()`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows) but even with this I still don't know how to do...

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use gtk_tree_selection_get_selected

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the [changed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeSelection.html#GtkTreeSelection-changed) signal on the TreeSelection.

It also sounds like you probably want to make sure the selection is in GTK_SELECTION_SINGLE mode (either done in Glade or by calling set_mode() on your TreeSelection.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some examples:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample (in the "TreeView with ListStore" section)
- https://srackham.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/vala-treeview-list-example/

Depending on the kind of store you are using as your [TreeModel](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeModel), you should read the [TreeStore](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeStore) and / or [ListStore](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.ListStore) documentation.

The key method of getting values is [TreeModel.get ()](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gtk+-3.0/Gtk.TreeModel.@get).